# What is the best way to empty a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

Is there a way to delete all files & sub-directories of a specified directory without iterating over them?

The non elegant solution:

```
public static void EmptyDirectory(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        // Delete all files
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        // Delete all folders
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2239b45a-3f19-4a2a-b5cd-050b3ee32b9d/how-can-i-check-folder-is-empty-or-not?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about System.IO.Directory.Delete?  It has a recursion option, you're even using it.  Reviewing your code it looks like you're trying to do something slightly different -- empty the directory without deleting it, right?  Well, you could delete it and re-create it :)

---

In any case, you (or some method you use) must iterate over all of the files and subdirectories. However, you can iterate over both files and directories at the same time, using [GetFileSystemInfos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach(System.IO.FileSystemInfo fsi in 
    new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).GetFileSystemInfos())
{
    if (fsi is System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
        ((System.IO.DirectoryInfo)fsi).Delete(true);
    else
        fsi.Delete();
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I don't see how it's more elegant than the original code. I just don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: This will drop all metadata, such as ACLs and timestamps. This may or may not be acceptable for a given use case

Comment: @jpaugh Deleting and re-creating directories would do that, but that's not what this solution does. No ACLs or timestamps will be lost except on files that are deleted, which, of course, are going to lose all information related to those files, I can't imagine expecting anything else if the file is permanently gone.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN "Well, you could delete it and re-create it." Are you saying that this does not match your code? I admittedly did not look at the code closely at first.

Comment: @jpaugh Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. That was presented as a silly option (thus the emoji), but the code implements a more serious solution, introduced by "After re-interpreting your question, this is the best I've got"... a different solution.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Maybe I'm dense, but I didn't get it very quickly. I hope my edits are in line with your (years-old!) thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

Why is that not elegant? It's clean, very readable and does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always just use Directory.Delete....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328748%28VS.71%29.aspx

Or if you want to get fancy, use WMI to delete the directory.

Comment: If I interpret his post correctly, he doesn't want to delete the directory, just the files and sub-directories in it.

Comment: Yeh, true, but Directory.Delete is still the best way. Deleting the directory and recreating an empty one in its place is more "elegant" and probably faster than iteration.

Comment: That approach wouldn't retain any non-inherited directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method based on the OPs original code, which I think is just fine and a bit more readable than other options.

I agree it would be nice to have a single method in the framework to delete the contents of a directory without deleting the directory, but in my opinion, this is the next best thing.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class DirectoryInfoExtensions
    {
        public static void EmptyDirectory(this DirectoryInfo di)
        {
            if (di.Exists)
            {
                foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }

                foreach (var directory in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    directory.Delete(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```