# DirectoryInfo.Delete vs Directory.Delete

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I want to delete the contents of some temp files so I am working on small program that deletes them for me. I have these two code samples but I'm confused as to:

1. Which code sample is better?
2. The first sample, code1, deletes the files 1 and 2 but the second sample, code2 will delete the contains of folder 1 and 2?

code1

```
    public void DeleteContains(string Pathz)
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> FolderToClear = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
        FolderToClear.Add(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\1"));
        FolderToClear.Add(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\2"));

        foreach (DirectoryInfo x in FolderToClear)
        {
            x.Delete(true);
        }
    }
```

code 2

```
    private void DeleteContents(string Path)
    {
        string[] DirectoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(Path);
        string[] FileList = Directory.GetFiles(Path);

        foreach (string file in FileList)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        foreach ( string directoryin DirectoryList)
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Delete whatever is in the folder?

Comment: Instead of naming variables like `Fil` and `Drectory`, try `file` and `directory`. It makes 9/10 people happier.

Comment: (I changed the title. Now it's your turn to change the code to make them "equivalent" in how they use the input or otherwise explain why/how it matters.)

Comment: @cheesemacfly  thanks and done.. what I am trying to do is deleting the MSN cashes and windows temp files using this small code... I think both codes are not useful i think there is something better... hope u suggest something thanks again :)

Comment: @xXghostXx can you describe what you mean by "something better". A better library? A better way to delete the cache? A faster way to delete?

Comment: @AboutDev A better way to delete the caches

Comment: @AboutDev the the fist code will allow me to add as much as I want paths but the second one will not allow me to add paths  or I have to create array of string for each path anyway better to do it ?? like to use the fist code to delete the contains of the folder NOT the folder and its contain

Comment: I think you are close to the "right" solution with Code 2 see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory). Next step is catching the exceptions.

Comment: @cheesemacfly  but the second one is not really useful because I have to create new array for each new path and new loops which is something painful ???? anyway better ???

Comment: You have no choice but to list what you want to delete...you don't need to create a string[] if this is the issue you have. Simply use a foreach like this: `foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Path)){           File.Delete(file);}`

Comment: ummmm waitting in hope that there is a better way... but I am thinking using the both code and ill add path depending on the folder if I am able to delete it or not... but still waiting guys any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I believe the OP wants a comparison of DirectoryInfo.Delete and Directory.Delete.

If you look at the decompiled source for each method (I used resharper to show me), you can see that DirectoryInfo.Delete and Directory.Delete both call the Delete method with 4 arguments. IMHO, the only difference is that Directory.Delete has to call Path.GetFullPathInternal to get the fullpath. Path.GetFullPathInternal is actually a very long method with lots of checks. Without doing a series of tests for performance, it would be unlikely to determine which is faster and by how much.

Directory.Delete

```
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    public static void Delete(String path, bool recursive)
    { 
        String fullPath = Path.GetFullPathInternal(path);
        Delete(fullPath, path, recursive, true); 
    }
```

DirectoryInfo.Delete

```
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)] 
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.Machine)]
    public void Delete(bool recursive) 
    {
        Directory.Delete(FullPath, OriginalPath, recursive, true);
    }
```

Comment: thanks what I am trying to do is deleting the MSN cashes and windows temp files using this small code and maybe in future i will add cookies files for browsers but I am working on it step by step  just to teach my self thinks I had leaned while doing small codes and develop it ... I think both codes are not useful or fixable enough i think there is something better... hope u suggest something thanks again

Comment: the the fist code will allow me to add as much as I want paths but the second one will not allow me to add paths  or I have to create array of string for each path anyway better to do it ?? like to use the fist code to delete the contains of the folder NOT the folder and its contain

Comment: What @cheesemacfly said in the comments above is correct. You can also use the Parallel libraries in order to delete things faster. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981410/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-deleting-files-in-a-directory-except-specific-file for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The first code sample will only delete the folders "C:\Users\user\Desktop\1" and "C:\Users\user\Desktop\2" regardless of what is passed in the parameter.

The second code sample will delete all files and folders that are inside the directory specified by the parameter.

Comment: yea I know man I wrote that in my question but anyway to let the code1 to do whats code 2 do  ??

Comment: the the fist code will allow me to add as much as I want paths but the second one will not allow me to add paths  or I have to create array of string for each path anyway better to do it ?? like to use the fist code to delete the contains of the folder NOT the folder and its contain